# pandas read_csv with storage_options working locally but not in Dataflow

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to import data from an API into my GBQ and want to use dataflow.

Due to reasons unknown and unimaginable to me, the API merely returns a URL of a ".csv.gz", which I then need to download and process before pushing the data into GBQ.

Furthermore, the API has authentication with a bearer token, so I was looking for a method to handle download and parsing of the data as well as the auth and found:

```py
pd.read_csv('https://app.SOMEPROVIDER.com/api/reporting/download/SOMEID.csv.gz', storage_options={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ bearer_token}, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
```

which works fantastically when using it in my Beam pipeline locally.

However, as soon as I upload the pipeline to dataflow and run it there, I get the error message

> ValueError: storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path

Full trace:

> ````
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1223, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 572, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> ".\filename.py", line 144, in process File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 610, in read_csv return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 462, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 819, in __init__ self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1050, in _make_engine return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options) #
> type: ignore[call-arg] File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1867, in __init__ self._open_handles(src, kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1362, in _open_handles self.handles = get_handle( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line
> 558, in get_handle ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line
> 286, in _get_filepath_or_buffer raise ValueError( ValueError:
> storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path During
> handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback
> (most recent call last): File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py",
> line 651, in do_work work_executor.execute() File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py",
> line 179, in execute op.start() File
> "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 63, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 64, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 79, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 80, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 84, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 353, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 261, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
> File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 268, in
> dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 353, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 712, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 713, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1225, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1290, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1223, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 752, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 875, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window
> File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1386, in
> apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 215, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
> File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 712, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 713, in
> apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1225, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1306, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1223, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process File
> "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 572, in
> apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process File
> ".\filename.py", line 144, in process File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 610, in read_csv return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 462, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 819, in __init__ self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1050, in _make_engine return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options) #
> type: ignore[call-arg] File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1867, in __init__ self._open_handles(src, kwds) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line
> 1362, in _open_handles self.handles = get_handle( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line
> 558, in get_handle ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer( File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line
> 286, in _get_filepath_or_buffer raise ValueError( ValueError:
> storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path [while
> running 'Fetch actual report data'] ```
> ````

Does anyone know why that works locally but not in the cloud? I assume it might have to do with the filesystem and temporary files - but then the error message does not make a lot of sense...

According to the the pandas doc, the storage_options parameter is handed to urllib for https links and only to fsspec for s3 and gcs paths. [see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Is "bearer_token" a string or a file-path ? If it's a file path it might not be available to VMs. Seems like the error is from the API you are using so I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was just a version issue. The interpretation of the storage options argument as authorization info did not exist in the pandas version that is included in the dataflow images and when I passed a local "wheel" of a the newest available pandas version with the `--extra_package` parameter, the issue resolved itself.